# Detect when div is "unloaded"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

**----- In short  -----**

I have a file, say **x.html**, that is load in some divs of others files (using the function jquery.load).

But **x.html** needs to know if another html is load in your place.

So, how can I know if the parent page loads another content into the div element that had **x.html** ?

**--- Verbose---**

This problem is similar to the problem of detect when a pop-up is closed:

I have some pages that load a page **x.html** into any of div.

For example: A page index.html

```
<html> 
...
<div id='contentX'>
</div>
...
<button id='btn1' onclick='functionThatLoadsXphpIntoDivContentX()'>
<button id='btn2' onclick='functionThatLoadsOtherContentIntoDivContentX()'>
...
<javascript>
function functionThatLoadsXphpIntoDivContentX(){
     $('#contentX').load('x.html');
}
function functionThatLoadsOtherContentIntoDivContentX(){
     $('#contentX').load('anotherPage.html');
}
</javascript>
</html>
```

when the user clicks btn2, the page **x.html** needs to know it, cause x.html needs to properly remove some elements (like tinyMCE).

I hope it's clear, but in the case it isn't, tell me why and I'll edit or comment.

Comment: you would have to use a query string to tell x.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you.  :(

Comment: Why don't you just check the content of div's ? If there is something in, just cancel the load ?

Comment: I can't to force the "client" (in this case, the parent page) to don't load another contents.

Comment: how about registering a 'change' event to the div (like on paste, keypress, etc..) to report the php? I cant really know for sure what you ment, so im commenting about it...

Comment: I don't need to execute php code. I just would like to make the page that x.html know that another page will be load in the same div that it is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such ".unload" method that you are looking for. The DIV isn't really unloaded, rather it's contents are changed. You will need to add a method call that "cleans up" the DIV before calling ".load" to change the DIV's contents.

Comment: But it means that the "parent page" must to call that function rather than the x.html, right ?

Comment: Vitor Lima, There is no "parent page." The contents of the DIV is set to the content returned from "x.html". I suggest you read the jQuery documentation for the ".load" method (http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get a better understanding of how it works and what it does.

Comment: I know it isn't really a parent page. That is the reason I wrote between quotation marks. I understood what I say. So, the only alternative I see is to create a function that "cleans up" into the file x.html and expect that any page that call $.load('x.html') call that function before load another content on the div...